# The Zero's are missing from the string after String Split in R

Tags: r

I have data set

```
dat
country     datacode  
Malta       014P100201
catalonia   014P100202
RAMANNAGAR  014P100203
KOLAR       221500955
MALLUR      221500956
MADDUR      221500970
KOPPA       221500955
```

I have done a string split on data code using the code:

```
 dat$splitcode=substr(dat$'datacode', 5, 30)
```

but the Output is as below and not matching my requirement.

```
country     datacode    SplitCode
Malta      014P100201   100201
catalonia   014P100202  100202
RAMANNAGAR  014P100203  100203
KOLAR       221500955      955
MALLUR      221500956      956
MADDUR      221500970      970
KOPPA      221500955       955
```

What i need is when the splitstring is done on '221500955' I want the output to be 00955 instead of 955.

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Check 'class(dat$SplitCode)' - if it says numeric, that's your problem. Numeric values do not save preceding zeroes, as they are non-significant. You should try conserve your split data using 'as.character'-function in order to conserve all preceding characters.

Comment: Post output of str(dat) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding as.character(). But even without it, all the 0s are coming:

```
> dat
     country   datacode
1      Malta 014P100201
2  catalonia 014P100202
3 RAMANNAGAR 014P100203
4      KOLAR  221500955
5     MALLUR  221500956
6     MADDUR  221500970
7      KOPPA  221500955
> 
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ country : Factor w/ 7 levels "catalonia","KOLAR",..: 6 1 7 2 5 4 3
 $ datacode: Factor w/ 6 levels "014P100201","014P100202",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 4
> 
> dat$splitcode_ori = substr(dat$'datacode', 5, 30) 
> dat$splitcode = as.character(substr(dat$'datacode', 5, 30) )
> 
> dat
     country   datacode splitcode_ori splitcode
1      Malta 014P100201        100201    100201
2  catalonia 014P100202        100202    100202
3 RAMANNAGAR 014P100203        100203    100203
4      KOLAR  221500955         00955     00955
5     MALLUR  221500956         00956     00956
6     MADDUR  221500970         00970     00970
7      KOPPA  221500955         00955     00955
> 
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ country      : Factor w/ 7 levels "catalonia","KOLAR",..: 6 1 7 2 5 4 3
 $ datacode     : Factor w/ 6 levels "014P100201","014P100202",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 4
 $ splitcode_ori: chr  "100201" "100202" "100203" "00955" ...
 $ splitcode    : chr  "100201" "100202" "100203" "00955" ...
>
```

For avoiding 0s to go away in write.csv, try write.csv(..., quote=TRUE)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i am still missing those 0's

Comment: The 0s are there in my answer above. Did you use as.character() ?

Comment: maybe `as.character` should be inside `substr`, like `substr(as.character(dat$datacode), 5, 30)`? It's hard to tell without giving us `str(dat)`

Comment: I have edited my answer above to give str() info also.

Comment: @rnso, I am getting it now. But when i write it to the CSV i am missing the zeros that the problem actually

Comment: Try quote=TRUE in write.csv

Comment: You should upvote/accept by clicking on tick next the answer.